# Walker Class in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create this navigation structure in my footer navigation:

```
<div class="footer container">
    <div class="footer-nav-containers">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-nav-containers">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-nav-containers">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty new to WordPress and would appreciate any help with how I would set this up as a Walker class. Thanks!

Comment: A great explanation here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401. What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to repeat your primary/header navigation in your footer?

Comment: thanks @NathanielFlick Basically I'm trying to convert what I hard coded into a WP theme. In the footer, I want to wrap each ul in a div called "footer-nav-containers". From what I've read, using the walker class would be my best option, but I'm not sure how I can get this structure.

Comment: Hi you could do Walker but I'm normally inclined to create an Appearance/Menu (you can call yours footer or simply call the primary nav again in footer if you want them to be the same items). Some great info here: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-menus-to-wordpress/

Comment: For a new menu you can look in functions.php for the nav_menu, duplicate it and call it something of your choosing, maybe footer_menu, then call it in your template: <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'new-menu' ) ); ?>

Answer (score -1):

First of all, that HTML is not valid.
You need to put `<li>` into `<ul>`
I assume you have registered "`footer`" menu

anyway....

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
      'theme_location' => 'footer', 
      'menu_id' => 'footer-menu' ,
      'container'         => 'div',
      'menu_class'        => 'footer container',
      ) 
    ); 
    ?>
```

And add jQuery for wrap 3 menu items.

```
var items = $(".footer container > li");
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i+=3) {
   items.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='footer-nav-containers'></div>");
}
```